# Finding the distribution which solves a given equation

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I know how to find a $u$ in the space of distributions on $\mathbb{R},$ i.e. $D'(\mathbb{R})$ which solves $xu=1.$ But I can't seem to be able to find $u$ in $D'(\mathbb{R})$ which solves $(x^2)u=1.$

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can write $(x^2)u$ as $x(xu),$ so you have the equation $x(xu)=1.$ This has the form $xv=1,$ which has solutions $v=\mathrm{pv}\frac1x + A\delta.$ Thus you get the equation $xu = \mathrm{pv}\frac1x + A\delta.$ This has solutions $u=\mathrm{fp}\frac{1}{x^2}-A\delta'+B\delta.$

Comment: How did you find the solution? $u=\mathrm{fp}\frac{1}{x^2}-A\delta'+B\delta.$

Comment: I dont know why
$u=\mathrm{fp}\frac{1}{x^2}-A\delta'+B\delta.$

I proved that $x \mathrm{fp}\frac{1}{x^2}= \mathrm{fp}\frac{1}{x}.$

Comment: \begin{align*}
 \left\langle x Pf \dfrac{1}{x^2} , \varphi \right\rangle  &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[ \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \dfrac{x \varphi(x)}{x^2} dx + \displaystyle\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \dfrac{x\varphi(x)}{x^2}  dx \right] \\
 &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[ \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \dfrac{\varphi(x)}{x} dx + \displaystyle\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \dfrac{\varphi(x)}{x}  dx \right] \\
 &= VP\left[ \dfrac{1}{x}\right] .
\end{align*}

Comment: @Bungmap. Do you know the solutions of $xu=\delta$?

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thank you Sir.